# esp32 flahing from ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, iot, esp32

I am trying to get esp-idf working with ubuntu. I see the usb tty port in /dev, as /dev/ttyUSB0.
Compilation of my blink program happened without any issues, in ubuntu, but when I tried to flash the image to esp32, I get the following error;

```
A fatal error occurred: Could not open /dev/ttyUSB0, the port doesn't exist
```

CMake Error at run_serial_tool.cmake:55 (message):

/home/lenovo/.espressif/python_env/idf5.1_py3.8_env/bin/python;;/home/lenovo/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py;--chip;esp32
failed

FAILED: CMakeFiles/flash

I am using ESP-Wroom32 development board. I flashed the same board from windows both through eclipse ide, and powershell. So, I kind of know the board is not the problem. Could anyone provide any lead?

Answer (score 5):

Found the issue to be related to permission. But it exposed only when I ran idf.py monitor on the port.
Running chmod 0777 /dev/ttyUSB0 solved it.
The error reported "port doesn't exist" is very different from actual error which is "Permission denied".

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I can't leave you a comment but, thank you, your solution helped me as well.

And just as a side note: I've done some further experiments and the `0666` is sufficient to perform the flash, at least on my configuration. Probably the problem is that `esptool.py` performs some action as a different user than the one which run the script itself

Comment: I did it. I added an answer because I found out that one doesn't need `0777`, `0666` is sufficient